# Getting unicode string from its code - C#

Tags: c#, unicode, string-concatenation

I know following is the way to use unicode in C#

```
string unicodeString = "\u0D15";
```

In my situation, I will not get the character code (*0D15*) at compile time. I get this from a XML file at runtime. I wonder how do I convert this code to unicode string? I tried the following

```
// will not compile as unrecognized escape sequence
string unicodeString = "\u" + codeFromXML; 

// will compile, but just concatenates u with the string got from XML file.
string unicodeString = "\\u" + codeFromXML;
```

How do I handle this situation?

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You want to use the [char.ConvertFromUtf32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.convertfromutf32.aspx) function.

```
string codePoint = "0D15";

int code = int.Parse(codePoint, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
string unicodeString = char.ConvertFromUtf32(code);
// unicodeString = "ക"
```

Comment: again showing Microsoft doesn't know the difference between actual text encodings and unicode itself...

Comment: Note that will throw when you pass it a UTF-16 surrogate.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an NUnit test showing arul and Adrian's solution - note that one solution starts with input in a string, while with the other solution the input starts in just a char.

```
    [Test]
    public void testConvertFromUnicode()
    {

        char myValue = Char.Parse("\u0D15");
        Assert.AreEqual(3349, myValue);

        char unicodeChar = '\u0D15';
        string unicodeString = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(unicodeChar);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, unicodeString.Length);
        char[] charsInString = unicodeString.ToCharArray();
        Assert.AreEqual(1, charsInString.Count());
        Assert.AreEqual((int) '\u0D15', charsInString[0]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape the character in the xml using a [character reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-charref):

```
<Config value="&#x0D15;" />
```

It will get read properly by c#'s xml parser (at least XElement.Load()).