# How to convert \uXXXX\uXXXX to plain text by C#

Tags: c#, string

```
string unicode = "\u0e23\u0e32";
```

How to convert \uXXXX\uXXXX to plain text by C#

Comment: I believe this will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994459/getting-unicode-string-from-its-code-c-sharp

Comment: To which medium are you out putting? Many fonts will not include those code points, so you need to ensure the output method can specify a suitable font.

Comment: @gideon Both code points are in the BMP so UTF-32 will not be an issue.

Comment: [Joel Spolsky](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) has a really good artical for unicode.

Comment: Guess I need to read that article. I'm doing that, nontheless, @Richard would you please elaborate what you mean. I'm clueless and curious.

Comment: @gideon These comments are far too short for a tutorial on Unicode encodings I'm afraid. Joel's article is a decent start.

Comment: @Richard yep. I'm on it. Thanks, after reading I'll figure out what you mean :)

Comment: If your language is Thai then use Codepage 10021.
`string unicode = "\u0e23\u0e32";`  
`Encoding cp = Encoding.GetEncoding(10021);`  
`var result = cp.GetString(cp.GetBytes(unicode));`